# Friendly 'From' Name with asp.net Webmail helper

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, webmail, webmatrix-2, razor-2

I am using the webmail helper in my ASP.NET razor webpages program. I am able to send emails perfectly.

my question:

Does the WebMail helper allow me to use a "Friendly" From name instead of only: noreply@mycompany.com? for example:

Webmail.From = *Friendly name + email*

Answer (score 2):

No - the WebMail helper does not allow you to set a display name. You will have to use System.Net.Mail classes directly if you require that functionality. That way you can use the [MailAddress class constructor that accepts two strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s17zfkf.aspx) - one to represent the email address, and the other to represent the display name.

Answer (score 1):

To add a friendly name edit the .From field of the WebMail class and make it:

```
WebMail.From = "\"Friendly Name\" <friendly.name@example.com>";
```